# Gene Name Finding

Tags: molecular-genetics, gene-expression, gene

X8HS20 - please help, I am not able to find the proper name or function of this gene in any database - can someone kindly help to figure out what it is ? I hypothesize that it is some gene of mitochondrial importance on the X chromosome- but I am not sure. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you give more information on where you found this name and why do you think it exists? You must have some source?

Comment: Thank you, but I can't disclose it - I think I managed to find an answer though, will check in with the organization which I derived the data from much later on, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found a possible match - it could be the V-Set Pre-B Cell Surrogate Light Chain 3 gene - called 8HS20. Derived from KEGG - will have to check in with more research papers to see why a X is placed before the 8HS20. Definitely not a clerical mistake on my side though.